# Calling insert function in c from a header file

Tags: c

My professor send me a library to insert,delete and search elements in a linked list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE
{
    char AM[12];
    char name[40];
    int semester;
    struct NODE *head;
    struct NODE *next;
    struct NODE *prev;
};

void init(struct NODE **head)
{
    *head=NULL;
}

struct NODE *Search (struct NODE *head,char CODE[],struct NODE **prev)
{
    struct NODE *tmp;
    *prev=NULL;
    tmp=head;
    while (tmp!=NULL && tmp->AM<CODE)
    {
        *prev=tmp;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    if (tmp==NULL)
    return NULL;
    if (tmp->AM==CODE)
    return tmp;
    return NULL;
}

struct NODE *Search2 (struct NODE *head,char name[],struct NODE **prev)
{
    struct NODE *tmp;
    *prev=NULL;
    tmp=head;
    while (tmp!=NULL && tmp->name<name)
    {
        *prev=tmp;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    if (tmp==NULL)
    return NULL;
    if (tmp->name==name)
    return tmp;
    return NULL;
}

int Insert (struct NODE **H,struct NODE P)
{
    struct NODE *cur,*prev;
    cur=Search(*H,P.AM,&prev);
    if (cur)
    return 0;
    cur=(struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof P);
    *cur=P;
    if (prev==NULL)
    {
        cur->next=*H;
        *H=cur;
    }
    else
    {
        cur -> next = prev -> next;
        prev -> next = cur;
    }
    return 1;
}

int Delete (struct NODE **H,char AM[])
{
    struct NODE *cur,*prev,*next;
    cur=Search(*H,AM,&prev);
    if (!cur)
    return 0;
    if (prev==NULL)
    cur=next;
    else
    prev->next=cur->next;
    free(cur);
    return 1;
}

void traverse (struct NODE *head)
{
    struct NODE *cur;
    cur=head;
    while (cur)
    {
        printf ("%p\n",cur);
        cur=cur->next;
    }
}
```

Now here is a piece of code from the source file that i created in an attempt to insert an element in the linked list:

```
case 1:printf ("Input AM,name and semester of student: "); 
tmp=(struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE)); 
if (tmp==NULL) 
exit(1); 
scanf("%s %s %d",tmp->AM,tmp->name,&tmp->semester); 
_flag=Insert(&head,*tmp); 
if(_flag) 
printf ("Student inserted succesfully!\n"); 
free(tmp);
break;
```

When i insert the element i get the "Student inserted succesfully" message,but when i call the search function to find that element,it returns NULL (meaning that the element is not in the list).How should i call the Insert function from the header file? (I assume the problem must be in the Insert function).Also in main() i have declared the following two:

```
struct NODE *head;
struct NODE *tmp;
```

Should i change something regarding those two?

Comment: `tmp->AM<CODE` : Use `strcmp` instead of `<`.

Comment: Not using all-uppercase names for anything else than macros or enum-constants is one of the few well accepted naming conventions. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. Your prof spreads bad coding style.

Comment: What happens when you single step debug through the code for insert and search?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the Search() and Search2() functions, where you've got things like this:

```
while (tmp!=NULL && tmp->AM<CODE)
```

and

```
if (tmp->AM==CODE)
return tmp;
```

You're comparing the pointers, rather than the contents of the strings. If you want to compare the strings, or find which is first alphabetically, use strcmp().

```
while (tmp!=NULL && strcmp(tmp->AM, CODE) < 0)
```

and

```
if (!strcmp(tmp->AM, CODE))
    return tmp;
```

The same goes for the comparison between tmp->name and name in Search2().